# Remove McAfee Safe Search bar

Tags: safari, search

The McAfee Safe Search bar is not aesthetically pleasing, and will never be used by me, is it possible to remove it from the Safari browser, while keeping McAfee and its internet security benefits?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal, and run:

```
cd /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins
ls
```

Does it show "something something McAfee"?

If yes, try moving it somewhere else (to be able to restore it later, if something goes wrong), replace `McAfeeFooBar` with the actual name (you can press tab to complete the name):

```
mv McAfeeFooBar ~/
killall Safari
```

and start Safari again. If the Toolbar is gone and McAfee still works, you're done!

If you get something along the lines of "permission denied" while trying the `mv` command, prepend it by `sudo` and enter your password when requested.

If this doesn't lead to the desired effect, or McAfee breaks, revert your changes by typing

```
cd
mv McAfeeFooBar /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/
```

again prepending the `mv` command with `sudo` if necessary.